# Position of a point on the boundary of a moving circle

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, circles, rotations

Consider a circular wheel with radius $r$ moving to the right along the ground at a constant velocity. The ground is the x-axis, and the wheel moves in the positive direction. Assume that $Q_0$ is at the origin, so that the position vector of $Q_0$ is the zero vector. Let $Q_t$ be the position of the point after t seconds ($Q_t$ always stays on the boundary of the circle for all $t$ and the point moves in clockwise-direction), and let $P_t$ be the
position of the centre of the wheel after t seconds, for all $t ≥ 0.$ I want to find

i) $\sigma \in \text {Bij}(\mathbb R^2) $ such that $P_{t+1} = \sigma (P_{t}) \,\,\, \forall t \geq 0.$

ii) $\tau \in \text {Bij}(\mathbb R^2) $ such that $Q_{t+1} = \tau (Q_{t}) \,\,\, \forall t \geq 0.$

Here Bij($\mathbb R^2$) is the set of all transformations on $\mathbb R^2.$

My answers:

i) $\sigma$ is the map $T_{A,\mathbb b} : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, $\mathbb x \mapsto A\mathbb x \,\,  + \dfrac{2\pi r}{T}t  $ where $A$ is the clockwise rotation matrix and $\mathbb b = \dfrac{2\pi r}{T}t $.

ii) I want to express $\tau$ as a product of transformations, defined geometrically. The definition of $\tau$ will certainly involve $P_t.$ But I don't know how to do it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Strange that $\sigma$ is the identity map if the wheel is rolling along the ground without sliding?!? A car moves!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net
please assume that the wheel does not slip at all

Answer (score 1):

The wheel is moving at a constant velocity, let's call it $v$. In one unit of time it changes $x$ by $v\cdot 1$, while keeping $y$ fixed, $y=r$. So $$(x_{t+1},y_{t+1})=(x_t+v,y_t)=(x_t,y_t)+(v,0)$$
The point of the wheel rotates around the axis at a constant angular speed. To describe the point in the fixed reference frame, you need to account for the fact that the axis is moving as well, so you would need to add the motion of the center. In the reference frame at the center of the axis $$x_t=-r\sin\omega t\\y_t=r(1-\cos \omega t)$$
When you add the motion of the center, $$x_t=vt-r\sin\omega t\\y_t=r(1-\cos \omega t)$$.
Here $\omega$ is the angular speed. If the wheel rotates without slipping, $$v=\omega r$$

Can you finish from here to write $\tau$? Write $x_{t+1}$ and $y_{t+1}$ in terms of the quantities at $t$.

**Note** that you are describing the cycloid motion, in case you want to look it up.

Comment: we have to express $\tau$ and $\sigma$ using euclidean geometry i.e. using transformations like rotations, reflections, translations etc.I have edited my question.

Comment: Note that $\sigma$ should not contain any rotation. The center of the wheel does not rotate around the origin. What you wrote for $\sigma$ is in fact $\tau$. For $\sigma$ you replace $A$ by the identity matrix $I$.

Comment: I understood $\sigma$ and realised my mistake. Do you mind elaborating why $T_{A,\mathbb b} : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ , $\mathbb x \mapsto A\mathbb x \,\,  + \dfrac{2\pi r}{T}t$ is $\tau$ ? Is $\mathbb x$ here the difference between the position vectors of $Q_t$ and $P_t$ ?

Comment: Just to make sure it is right, your $\textrm{x}$ is a vector with two components. Then your last term should be multiplied by $(1,0)$. You both rotate and translate $x$, but you just rotate $y$. The motion of the point on the edge of the wheel is a combination of the rotation around the  center, plus you need to add the motion of the center (which is just a translation parallel to $x$ axis.

Comment: I understood what you are saying. The term $\dfrac{2\pi r}{T}t$ needs to be multiplied by $(1,0)$. Apologies for not doing that previously. So I'm correct in saying that $\mathbb x$  is the difference between the position vectors of $Q_t$ and $P_t$?

Comment: $\textrm{x}$ is the $Q_t$ in the fixed reference frame. The difference between $Q_t$ and $P_t$ is the position relative to the center.

Comment: So if $\mathbb x$ is the position vector of $Q_t$, the definition of $\tau$ does not  involve $P_t$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115743/discussion-between-andrei-and-rhombus).